# Array to json using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to pass an array through jQuery's `ajax`. The problem is that when I try to pass the array created in JavaScript to `JSON`, it returns something empty. I even try `console.log`, but when I try to convert it to JSON there is nothing. Here is a representation of how I do it:

```
var data = [];
data['name'] = 'test';
data['mail'] = 'test';
data['pass'] = 'test';
console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // result []
```

Comment: It appears that you're mistaking an "associative array" (read: object) for an array.

Comment: How could I do then?

Comment: `var data = {}` - use curly brackets for an object.

Comment: [Consider spending some time reviewing the tag wiki page and using some of the listed links for introductory JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info).

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this question. Please stop with the downvotes. Not everyone is a Node Ninja^tm

Comment: well, other than it being poorly researched and not useful, yea, nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every array is an object. You are assigning object properties with the `data['name'] = 'test'` syntax. Arrays are indexed with integers and they "must" be in sequence. try `a[0] = 'foo'`. or `Array.push`